# Помогите правильно оформить строку сложения, деления, вычетания

Tags: python, float, int

Попытался написать код, но выводит исключение:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'int'server.py:75
```

Сам код:

```
disk_space_res_free_2 = 1233434534
formula = ((((disk_space_res_free_2 * 512) / 1024 / 1024) - 833) / 1024) * 0,9765625)
print = formula
```

Помогите правильно написать код, что бы все сложилось, поделилось, умножилось

Comment: `print(formula)` ;)

Comment: `int(number_in_string)`

Comment: Вижу только лишнюю скобку справа, запятую вместо точки в `0,9765625` и странно написанный print, если это исправить, всё печатает, нет там никаких юникодов.

Comment: У вас видимо в `disk_space_res_free_2` какая-то строка, причём русскими буквами, а не число, как вы пишете.

Comment: да это с формулой понятно, я косякнул сюда запили, походу реально переобразовывать в число надо.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае корректный код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```py
disk_space_res_free_2 = 1233434534
formula = ((((disk_space_res_free_2 * 512 / 1024 / 1024) - 833) / 1024) * 0.9765625)
print(formula)
```

Скобки расставлены в соответствии с [приоритетом](https://tirinox.ru/python-op-precedence/)

Comment: С одной стороны приоритет в выражении `/ 1024 * 0.9765625` понятно какой, а с другой стороны лучше в таких случаях всё же явно скобки писать, чтобы уж никаких сомнений. "Явное лучше чем неявное" и всё такое

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, учту